# mysql: join two tables with two fields in common to get a third table

Tags: mysql, join, phpmyadmin

I need some help using mysql and phpmyadmin; 
I have two tables with two column fields in common, and I need to join both tables into a third where this two fields of each table are in common; also the reference table is the table 1, so the idea is that 3rd table is actually table 1 with the aditional of table 2 adding value 1 and value 2 from table table 2 into table 1 where Column 1 and Column 2 are the same for both tables... for example:

table1:
            ID, Column1, Column2, Value1, Value2
            1 ,   DAN     ,  Citi1 ,    1  ,   3
            2 ,   JUAN    ,  Citi1 ,    5  ,   5
            3 ,   DAN     ,  Citi2 ,    3  ,   7
            4 ,   PEDRO ,  Citi1 ,    2  ,   4
            5 ,   JUAN    ,  Citi2 ,    7  ,   9
            
            table2:
            ID, Column1, Column2, Value1, Value2
            1 ,   DAN   ,  Citi1 ,    5  ,   0
            2 ,   JUAN  ,  Citi1 ,    0  ,   3
            3 ,   DAN    ,  Citi2 ,    4  ,   5
            4 ,   JUAN  ,  Citi2 ,    6  ,   8

table 3, join:

ID, t1/t2.Column1 , t1/t2.Column2, t1.Value1, t1.Value2, t2.Value1, t2.Value2

ID, t1.Column1, t1.Column2, t1.Value1, t1.Value2, t2.Value1, t2.Value2
            1 ,   DAN        ,  Citi1          ,    1         ,   3          ,       5       ,       0
            2 ,   JUAN       ,  Citi1          ,    5         ,   5          ,       0       ,       3
            3 ,   DAN         ,  Citi2          ,    3         ,   7          ,       4       ,       5
            4 ,   PEDRO     ,  Citi1          ,    2         ,   4          ,       0       ,       0
            5 ,   JUAN        ,  Citi2           ,    1        ,   3          ,       6       ,       8

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
  t1.Column1,
  t1.Column2,
  t1.Value1,
  t1.Value2,
  COALESCE(t2.Value1, 0),
  COALESCE(t2.Value2, 0)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
    AND t1.column1 = t2.column1
    AND t1.column2 = t2.column2
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90a73/2)</kbd>

Comment: Thansks for your quick answer @FilipeSilva, but this will join both tables with the criterias where ID on t1 is equal ID on table 2? what I want is the join where Column 1 and also Column 2 from table 1 are equal from table 2...

Comment: @dhacohen. I didn't see that. I thought they were always equals.. See if my edited answer solves that

Comment: Thanks Filipe, I used your query and I think it works. It works as a select to show me the data, but how can I create a table that constntly is filled with this data? If I use your query in phpmyadmin, it woks, but doesn't fill any table... how can I use this query to fill a third table? one created by the join of the other two...

Comment: Just create that table with that table with the columns you want and then do: insert into NEWTABLE select... the query in my answer. Let me know if it works.